# Error while putting div side by side

Tags: html, css

**I am new in coding and i want some help. while putting div tag side by side I am getting my links also in side. Kindly help me to solve out my problem**

My  Code are attached:-
jsfiddle

Comment: Please include the code in your post (not images of the code).  Or consider putting together a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Include relevant code in a code snippet, demonstrate what methods have already been explored and specify the intended end-result.

Answer (score 0):

pasting your code helps but I also see an issue in your css.

.box2 p {} has two syntax errors. Line 1 has ' after ; and line 2 has ; where there should be ":"

Use tools like codepen.io and jsfiddle.net to help you with start out code. A good IDE like Atom, Brackets, phpstorm, can help highlight where you have code issues and give you hints.

Comment: Check my pen [link](https://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/vJGoGj) to see the correct code

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/Lyxk55bb/embed/html,css,result/"></script>

Comment: I think you mean jsfiddle.net/Lyxk55bb. Where do you want the links to go?

When you specify the width and then float the box, the remaining content occupies the remaining space on the device screen.

Comment: This is your question

"I am new in coding and i want some help. while putting div tag side by side I am getting my links also in side. Kindly help me to solve out my problem"

What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxk55bb/ in this link you will get my code and result also. in result my links are also shown in side. i don't want to show them

Comment: add class .hide to <a> tag.

`.hide {
    display:none;
  }`